# Can adding a prefix change the auxiliary verb?

Tags: perfect-tense, auxiliary-verb

Usually, when I have to conjugate a verb with a prefix (not necessarily separable!) in *Perfekt*, I automatically associate the same auxiliary verb, say

> [verschwimmen, ich *bin* verschwommen] *because of* [schwimmen, ich *bin* geschwommen.]

and

> [anmachen, ich *habe* angemacht] *because of* [machen, ich *habe* gemacht]

I'm almost sure that the following statement is not entirely true but my verb-repertoire, so far, hasn't being enough to find an exception to the following statement:

> *Adding a prefix to a verb doesn't change its auxiliary.*

If it doesn't hold, can somebody state a weaker rule (i.e. more hypothesis), so that it does hold?

Comment: *kommen* and *bekommen* would be a counterexample, though they are very different in meaning and might no even have the same etymological origin.

Comment: *befallen* (haben) and *fallen* (sein) would be a counterexample of verbs which almost certainly share their etymological origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the statement is not true. E.g., reflexive verbs always form *haben* perfect, so if you derive a reflexive verb from a non-reflexive *sein* perfect verb, the auxiliary changes:

> Er ist in die falsche Richtung geschwommen. Er hat sich völlig verschwommen.

(Same with *sich verlaufen*, *sich verfahren*, *sich verrennen*. *Verschwimmen* unrelatedly also means *to become blurred*, non-reflexive, with *sein* perfect.)

In some cases, a prefix changes the meaning of a verb from expressing a state to expressing a transition or the other way round, also causing a change in the auxiliary:

> Sie ist erst nach Mitternacht eingeschlafen. Deshalb hat sie insgesamt nur fünf Stunden geschlafen.
>
> Die vermeintliche Leiche hat noch gezuckt. Der Bestatter ist zusammengezuckt, als er das bemerkt hat.

A prefix can also transform an intransitive verb with *sein* perfect into a transitive one:

> Ich habe meine neuen Schuhe eingelaufen. Dazu bin ich jeden Tag ein paar Kilometer in ihnen gelaufen.

(There are also unrelated intransitive uses of *einlaufen*: *Das Hemd ist eingelaufen. Das Schiff ist in den Hafen eingelaufen.*)

Canoo lists [rules when to use *sein* or *haben*](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Tempora/HabenSein.html). From this, you can in fact conclude that the auxiliary of prefixed verbs is quite unrelated to the auxiliary used with the base verb, except for very few cases like *loswerden*, *eingehen* where the original auxiliary is retained in spite of the normal rules.

Comment: That link you provide is great!